# Jasmine- Custom reporter using

Tags: protractor

i want the result for assertion present in each page of application separately instead of combine result for complete spec in conf file How to get that??
I have tried with jasmine custom reporter but getting complete spec failed assertion result combined.

Comment: Take a look at the [`jasmine-spec-reporter`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/jasmine-spec-reporter).

Comment: thanks @alecxe for response but i want result that how many no. of assertion fail in each page in conf.js onPrepare() method instead of console as we can get through jasmine custom reporter specDone(). but it gives for complete spec but my need is for page.